# How to sniff css on div from existing website to add inline css to that div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, froala

I would like to sniff the CSS that is currently applied to a certain div on my website, in order to insert inline style to that div (think of it like inlining before sending an email, even though it is before inserting into Word).

I'm well aware of inliner tools that inline the style for the whole webpage, and that I could send the whole webpage to tools like that (https://github.com/peterbe/premailer for instance), but I would like to avoid sending the whole page and grabbing the div afterward, if possible because it seems quite barbaric.

Any idea on how to grab the style currently applied to an element? I'm open to pre- and post-rendering.

If relevant, it's a div inside a FROALA editor, but useClass is a no-go, many styles are not set in classes but rather directly in dom tag styles:

```
a {
    color: ponytail's rainbow;
}
```

Comment: Nothing [here](https://www.google.nl/search?q=javascript+get+current+css+site:stackoverflow.com) ?

Comment: Just look in the browsers Devtools. Look at the "Computed" tab and you can see all the final styles that are applied to an element.

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan, that's a good start, that I couldn't find for reasons. But I need to inline the style after detecting it, and I still need to do that after detecting the style :)

Comment: @McVenco I need to do that dynamically, not simply one-shot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.getComputedStyle(element[, pseudoElt]);
```

> The window.getComputedStyle() method returns an object that reports the values of all CSS properties of an element after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.  Individual CSS property values are accessed through APIs provided by the object or by simply indexing with CSS property names.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Combining that with

```
var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);

for (prop in elementStyle) {
  if (elementStyle.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    out += "  " + prop + " = '" + elementStyle[prop] + "' > '" + computedStyle[prop] + "'\n";
  }
}
```

does the trick

Comment: Thanks, that's part of the answer, but I still don't see/know how to apply said style to an existing element. I need to apply found style and inline it (for the div to contain all relevant styles by itself for exporting it afterward)

Comment: If you follow the first link it shows working examples on how to extract the properties you want.

see HTMLElement.style for applying.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Comment: I actually tried that, but it doesn't work (no error though, so I'm looking for solutions)
See http://jsfiddle.net/torendill/h43yaL8z/

Comment: have you tried reading the documentation? I mean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style gives an example of exactly how to do it.

Comment: Was in the process, I actually was kind of re-writing it in my fiddle :/ thanks for the help !